# How do you generate Pseudorandom Gradient for perlin noise?

Tags: gradient, noise

I have a question. so I read this article about classic and simplex noise. [here](https://weber.itn.liu.se/%7Estegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf). I don't understand how would you generate a gradient for grid points. it says that you should pick 8 or 16 gradients within the unit circle, but how should those gradients repeat over time?

Answer (score 0):

The gradient noises are often made by generating a pseudo-random vector for each grid point but the method described here uses a set of pregenerated vector and :

> To associate each grid point with exactly one gradient, the integer coordinates of the point can
> be used to compute a hash value, which in turn can be used as the index into a look-up table of
> the gradients.

if the hash function is periodic, the noise will be periodic too and that is the case in the article (you can see it in the example code at the end).